# Primary decomposition of $(x^2, xy, xz, yz)$ in $K[x, y, z]$

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals, primary-decomposition

> Suppose $K$ is a field and consider the ideal $(x^2, xy, xz, yz)$ of $K[x, y, z]$. Find a primary decomposition of $(x^2, xy, xz, yz)$.

I have read about a strategy of finding primary decomposition using $\gcd$ of generators as follow:

Using $\gcd(y, z)=1$, we can get
$$(x^2, xy, xz, yz)=(x^2, xy,xz, y) \cap (x^2,xy,xz, z)=(x^2, xz, y)\cap(x^2,xy,z)$$
Since $\gcd(x, z)=1$, 
$$(x^2,xz,y)=(x^2, x, y)\cap (x^2,y,z)=(x,y) \cap (x^2, y, z)$$
and similarly
$$(x^2,xy,z)=(x,z)\cap(x^2,y,z)$$
Now put everything together and get
$$(x^2,xy,xz, yz)=(x,y)\cap (x,z)\cap(x^2,y,z)$$
It seems all ideals are now primary. Am I applying the strategy correctly?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.